# Move collapsed rows with parent row in Datatables when reordering

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I have a table containing parent and child rows. Child rows can be collapsed using bootstraps default collapse mechanism. All rows can be reordered using datatables rowReorder. Now if I drag&drop a parent row, it's child rows are not moved, of course. How can I achieve that behavior?

Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bt2x4hof/) of what I currently have, use the salary column to start dragging a row:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    "columnDefs": [{
      targets: 0,
      visible: false
    }],

    rowReorder: {
      selector: 'td:last-child'
    },

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/rowreorder/1.1.2/css/rowReorder.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/rowreorder/1.1.2/js/dataTables.rowReorder.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <table id="example" class="display nowrap" width="100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Seq</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Start date</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <th>Seq</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Start date</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td><i class="btn btn-xs fa fa-list-ul" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".collapsed1">+</i><b>Tiger Nixon (parent)</b>
        </td>
        <td>System Architect</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>2011/04/25</td>
        <td>$3,120</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="collapse collapsed1">
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Garrett Winters (child)</td>
        <td>Director</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>63</td>
        <td>2011/07/25</td>
        <td>$5,300</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="collapse collapsed1">
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Ashton Cox (child)</td>
        <td>Technical Author</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>66</td>
        <td>2009/01/12</td>
        <td>$4,800</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td><b>Cedric Kelly(parent)</b>
        </td>
        <td>Javascript Developer</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>2012/03/29</td>
        <td>$3,600</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td><b>Jenna Elliott (parent)</b>
        </td>
        <td>Financial Controller</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>33</td>
        <td>2008/11/28</td>
        <td>$5,300</td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>

  <ul>
    <li>Collapse/show child entries of Tiger Nixon using the plus sign.</li>
    <li>Drag rows by touching the salary column.</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use DataTable's child feature instead.

Here's the JSbin of demo
http://live.datatables.net/cihefawi/17

Modify it to add child rows dynamically, using ajax or something.

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation of parent and child rows is not right because you are not using any of the existing data table features here.

You are adding a patch(collapsible) for parent-child rows and for it to support you will have to add many other patches as well to support other features of data tables, like: sorting, searching etc.

I would recommend you to look at this [link](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html). It shows how you can implement collapsible data/details. You can modify the content to look like a row but still the features of data-tables will not work on those rows. Ideally they are only supposed to work on parent rows. Rest depends on your requirements and implementation.